# I'd like to get assets from the wallet using blockfrost, but some errors occur

Tags: blockfrost

[image]

export const callApi = async (endPoint: string) => {
try {
const request: string = env.REACT_APP_BLOCKFROST_URL + endPoint
const response = await fetch(request, {
//@ts-ignore
headers: {
"Content-Type": "application/json",
project_id: process.env.REACT_APP_BLOCKFROST_KEY,
},
method: "GET",
})
let data = await response.json()
return data
} catch (error) {}
}

export const findAssets = async (stakeAddress: string) => {
const endPoint = `accounts/${stakeAddress}/addresses/assets`
const result = await callApi(endPoint)

return result
}
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see in the error message, the address you provide is not in the expected format.

Addresses on testnets start with "addr_test1" but the address you provide starts with "addr1" (probably a mainnet address).

Try to add a testnet address to the request and it should work.

Example testnet address: `addr_test1qpmtp5t0t5y6cqkaz7rfsyrx7mld77kpvksgkwm0p7en7qum7a589n30e80tclzrrnj8qr4qvzj6al0vpgtnmrkkksnqd8upj0`

Also note that you probably want to use the PreProd network instead of the testnet. Testnet has been broken a while ago.

Comment: Thanks for your great answer!

Comment: You're welcome. I see you're new here. If this has answered your question, you can mark the answer as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the error message, you're using invalid (mainnet) address against testnet endpoint